# How to properly conditioning Union type in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I wrote a python function that handles list of int or list of list of int, i.e. `[1,2,3]` or `[[1,2],[3,4]`, as follows:

```
from typing import Sequence, Union
IntSeq = Sequence[int]

def foo(a: Union[IntSeq, Sequence[IntSeq]]):
    if isinstance(a, Sequence) and isinstance(a[0], int):
        # here type of a equals IntSeq
        b: IntSeq = a
```

However, mypy told me the below error:

```
$ mypy bar.py
```

```
test.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[Sequence[int], Sequence[Sequence[int]]]", variable has type "Sequence[int]")
```

How to vanish this error?

Comment: What should be an output?

Comment: @Camile mypy should print no output

Comment: How do you call this function? Does calling this function result in error?

Comment: @shahkalpesh run [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) over the script.

Comment: Search for "incompatible types in assignment" on [this page](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_inference_and_annotations.html). It explains the rationale. Looking at your code, it appears that you cant assign a (which is a union of 2 types) to b (of type IntSeq).

Comment: @shahkalpesh You probably miss the issue here. The assignment `b : IntSeq = a` cannot have incompatible types, since the instances are tested for and ensured to be equal. `b` cannot be used to add anything illegal to `a` since it is protected. However, it can still be that this is hard for `mypy` to infer and therefore it will not allow it.

Comment: @JohanL Thanks, that's what I wanted to say. I think it is hard for mypy to infer, too. So I want to know how to code the conditioning so that mypy can properly infer the type.

Comment: I don't have a good answer but at least you can supress the mypy error by a `typing.cast` call. But then you don't get any actual type checking done.